# Crystal Reports: error on massive exporting to PDF

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have developed an application that exports certain reports to PDF, it works fine but after exporting over 40 reports consecutively I get the following exception:

> This field name is not known.
>   Details: errorKind
>   Error in File temp_625c5d7e-28ae-4f51-adfe-4f64b9bc0ecf {B3644446-703B-4A71-AD77->8BE803C6F157}.rpt:
>   Error in formula  saldocic: 'shared numbervar saldocic;'

Crystal Reports version is 13.

I will appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is an error in the report, not in your code.  Identify which report is failing, then run it in the design environment (i.e. Crystal Reports) to see where it fails; this should also give you a more-descriptive error message.